# Query to return 2nd value if there are two, null if just one

Tags: sql, sql-server

The filtered table (code) may have these values

```
 code_type    date              id          
 TM       1/1/2011        2342 (random unique id)
 TM       2/1/2011        3298  (random unique id)
```

The table may have no TM records, one TM record, or it may have two TM records (never more).

If there's only one value, my output needs to be like this (blank or null values). If there's two records, the code2 and date2 fields would be filled in. If there are no TM records, all fields need to be null or empty.

```
code_type1   date1          code_type2     date2
TM       1/1/2011
```

I'm doing this in a subquery in the select clause, not sure if that will make any difference. I'm thinking I need a CASE statement?

Using SQL Server 2008

edit: The code id is random and not necessarily 1 or 2 as I had originally written this

Comment: Did I miss something? Where are "code1/code2" being pulled from? (Are they from the ID column?)

Comment: I edited the original code table. Code1/code2 should be coming from the code table, column code_type.

Comment: So my answer should work for you then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH YourQuery(code,[date],id) As
(
SELECT  'TM', '1/1/2011', 1 union all
SELECT  'TM', '2/1/2011', 2 
),
Numbered AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) RN
FROM YourQuery
)
SELECT 
     code1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN code END),
     date1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN [date] END),
     code2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN=2 THEN code END),
     date2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN=2 THEN [date] END)
FROM Numbered
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your restriction that there will NEVER be more than 2 records, this is very easy to do in a cross-platform way with only standard SQL; all you need is a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT
  Code1.Code_Type AS Code_Type1,
  Code1.Date AS Date1,
  Code2.Code_Type AS Code_Type2,
  Code2.Date AS Date2
FROM Code AS Code1
LEFT JOIN Code AS Code2
  ON (Code1.Code_Type = Code2.Code_Type)
  AND (Code1.ID < Code2.ID)
LEFT JOIN Code AS EarlierCode
  ON (Code1.Code_Type = EarlierCode.Code_Type)
  AND (Code1.ID > EarlierCode.ID)
WHERE
  (EarlierCode.ID IS NULL)
```

This is assuming that 'lower ID' is the way to determine which one is 'code1' and which is 'code2'. If it's date, then use that instead in the last line of each `JOIN`.

An explanation, if it's not clear: you start with each row in the table (`Code1`). You then join the table onto itself twice: `Code2` represents anything with a higher ID (there'll be only one of these, according to your premis), and `EarlierCode` represents a lower one. Because if you DO have two rows, you don't want it twice (once with the earlier value in `Code1` and the later in `Code2`, once with the later in `Code1` and `Code2` left null), you have 'EarlierCode', which represents something earlier than `Code1`. If there is one, you leave that row out (the `WHERE` clause).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  code1 = (SELECT code FROM TABLENAME WHERE id = 1),
  date1 = (SELECT [date] FROM TABLENAME WHERE id = 1),
  code2 = (SELECT code FROM TABLENAME WHERE id = 2),
  date2 = (SELECT [date] FROM TABLENAME WHERE id = 2)
```

You can test this with the following script:

```
DECLARE @code TABLE (
code char(2),
[date] char(30),
id int )

INSERT INTO @code (code, [date], id) VALUES ('TM', '1/1/2011', 1)
INSERT INTO @code (code, [date], id) VALUES ('TM', '2/1/2011', 2)

SELECT 
  code1 = (SELECT code FROM @code WHERE id = 1),
  date1 = (SELECT [date] FROM @code WHERE id = 1),
  code2 = (SELECT code FROM @code WHERE id = 2),
  date2 = (SELECT [date] FROM @code WHERE id = 2)
```

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer: _Constructive_ criticism would be nice, instead of being condescending. Also, if you can do better post your version.

Comment: If the rows with id=1 and id=2 are deleted then the query will return all nulls. I pretty sure the query will not 'fail epicly'. Read the user's question again...I think your comprehension of the problem 'failed epicly'.

Comment: My "comprehension of the problem" is right on. You should *never* write a query that depends on a field having a specific value. Both of these rows could have any arbitrary number as an id, and you should therefore just select all data, without a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I edited the question for clarity. My apologies. The ids will not necessarily be '1' and '2'. They can be any unique value.